# How come I don't have package updates in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum

I last updated my Fedora 14 install weeks ago, so I expected a slew of new packages waiting for me, but after I run `yum update`, I instead get:

```
...
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

**update**:

`rpm -qi sudo` gives version **1.7.4p4**

`yum -v repolist` gives:

```
Loading "langpacks" plugin
Loading "presto" plugin
Loading "refresh-packagekit" plugin
Adding en_US to language list
Config time: 0.074
Yum Version: 3.2.28
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.174
Repo-id      : fedora
Repo-name    : Fedora 14 - i386
Repo-revision: 1287926872
Repo-tags    : binary-i386
Repo-distro-tags: [cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:14]: rawhide
Repo-updated : Sun Oct 24 15:44:32 2010
Repo-pkgs    : 17,883
Repo-size    : 20 G
Repo-metalink: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-14&arch=i386
  Updated    : Sun Oct 24 15:44:32 2010
Repo-expire  : 604,800 second(s) (last: Thu Jan 13 20:00:21 2011)

Repo-id      : updates
Repo-name    : Fedora 14 - i386 - Updates
Repo-revision: 1295548217
Repo-tags    : binary-i386
Repo-updated : Thu Jan 20 21:32:10 2011
Repo-pkgs    : 4,500
Repo-size    : 7.2 G
Repo-metalink: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f14&arch=i386
  Updated    : Thu Jan 20 21:32:10 2011
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Thu Jan 13 20:00:49 2011)

repolist: 22,383
```

Comment: this is not an answer... but do you have all your repos installed and configured? I mean does it have any any place to get packages from out of the box? some repo distro's don't set up any by default

Comment: @xeno I am able to install packages.

Comment: k that was my only thought

Comment: `sudo` was updated to version 1.7.4p5-1.fc14 on January the 17. Can you check with `rpm -qi sudo` which version (including release) you have and also include the output of `yum -v repolist`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repository cache is out of date, clean it and execute the update again:

```
yum clean expire-cache
yum update
```